# kuberenets pods shows different ulimit open files than the host

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes

I have a K8s cluster up and running on Azure VMs.

after getting:

> java.io.IOException: Too many open files in system

on one of the pods, I checked the open files limits by calling:

> ulimit -a | grep "open files"

on both, the host (via ssh), and got:

> open files                      (-n) 1024

and from within the pod (via 'exec' the pod), and got:

> bash-4.3# ulimit -a | grep "open files"
>
> open files                      (-n) 1048576

my question is how is it possible to have different values (the pod 'see' higher limit than the underlined host), and also which of the limits counts - will it break if more than 1024 open fd's get opened?

the relevant pod image based from 'alpine-java'.

the host os is: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708

Comment: Really good question, even I am looking for this answer

Answer (score 0):

For Ulimit option, you shoud change it from docker's unit file on your vm

```
    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd \
      --iptables=false \
      --ip-masq=false \
      --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock \
      --log-level=error \
      --storage-driver=overlay \
      --default-ulimit nofile=70000:70000 \
      --default-ulimit nproc=70000:70000
    Restart=on-failure
    RestartSec=5
```

Comment: thanks for the helpful info: you are right, I checked the docker.service file and it shows: LimitNOFILE=1048576
But I still don't understand if this number takes precedence over the host limit? in other words, is this number relevant while the host limit is lower?

Comment: Hi It is a very good question. We have to test it. A Jar file inside docker should open too many files while monitoring the host system. By this way we catch it.

Comment: These configuration should be set in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file